# ffmpeg: Why did my capture speed drop? (can no longer capture using same command)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, capturing

I've been using the following command to capture video with ffmpeg for the past two months using my Blackmagic Intensity Pro 4K capture card:

`ffmpeg -bm_v210 1 -rtbufsize 1500M -threads 4 -f decklink -i "Intensity Pro 4K@20" -c:a copy -c:v prores -profile:v 1 movie1.mov`

This has been fine although occasionally I get a "Decklink input buffer overrun!" error, in which case I have to restart the capture.

However, starting yesterday, I am getting a "Desklink input buffer overrun!" error every time.

```
[decklink @ 0000000002552cc0] Decklink input buffer overrun!bitrate=479405.2kbits/s speed=0.849x
    Last message repeated 1 times
[decklink @ 0000000002552cc0] Decklink input buffer overrun!bitrate=480001.5kbits/s speed=0.842x
    Last message repeated 8 times
[decklink @ 0000000002552cc0] Decklink input buffer overrun!bitrate=480685.0kbits/s speed=0.842x
    Last message repeated 15 times
```

So it looks like my SSD is no longer fast enough to write the data-- but why?  It worked fine for the past two months.

I'm capturing onto a Sandisk Extreme Pro SSD (960 GB).  The drive only has 10GB of data on it.  I manually ran TRIM just a moment ago, but that didn't help.  The SanDisk SSD Dashboard shows it has "99%" life remaining.

I have also disabled OneDrive, Dropbox, and all other software I could find that might write to the system during capture.

Comment: Replace `movie1.mov` with `-map 0 -f null -` to see if it's disk-related. Note: no file will be saved, so this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Mulvya When I make the replacement, I get the same error.  What does that mean?

Comment: More info: When I capture to dnxhr (hq) instead of prores (lt), even though the dnxhr bitrate is ~850000 kbit/sec vs ~450000 kbit/sec for prores, dnxhr works, but not prores.

Comment: What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: 3.2.0.  Can't use the builds of 3.2.2 or 3.2.4 because the "enable_decklink" flag isn't turned on so the capture card doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since it also happens with `-f null`, but not with another Codec, the CPU load during the capture is a possible explanation. You did not mention it in your question. Is there any specific reason to use `-threads 4`? Try raising that number or omit the parameter.